# Not able to display message on Error Message on Toast from server response

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programming, i have developed one application in which i am trying to login with user credentials as am unable to display the error toast message from server response but in Logcat am able to see the message. any other way to show the error

```
@Override
                public void success(JsonObject jsonObject, Response response) {
                    Log.d("Login", jsonObject.toString());
                    dialog.dismiss();

                    JsonObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject();
                    String status = jsonObject1.get("status").getAsString();
                    statuss = Boolean.parseBoolean(status);
                    if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                        String otp_status = jsonObject1.get("otpstatus").getAsString();

                        if (otp_status.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {

                            JsonObject jsonObject2 = jsonObject1.get("data").getAsJsonObject();

                            String userid = jsonObject2.get("userid").getAsString();
                            String email = jsonObject2.get("email").getAsString();
                            String phone = jsonObject2.get("phone").getAsString();


                            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    getActivity().finish();
                                    Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    startActivity(i);


                                }
                            });

                        } else {

                        }
                    } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + jsonObject1.get("message").getAsString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What's the response text that you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show your toast in `runOnUiThread()` another thing you are mapping `boolean` value to `string`, i.e not right way, try this way

```
 getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
     if (status) {
    //will execute if status is true
    }else{
    //will execute if status is false
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Hello" + jsonObject1.get("message").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Toast is also should be shown in UI thread. Also show us how you display error in logs and also put logs here please.